# How to rebuild java files in React Native?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I made a change to the file `ReactWebViewManager.java`, which is a file inside the react-native package. (full path to the file is `node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java`). However the changes I make to the file do not seem to take effect. I deleted the entire file to test this theory and the app continued to work fine, so it seems I need recompile/rebuild/clear the cache of the react-native package. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to run the following command every time you make changes to Java files: `react-native run-android`